# How can I change an email string to hide the identity with C#

Tags: c#

my C# code is returning this from WebAPI

```
        return Ok(new
        {
            email = user.Email,
            sent = true
        });
```

I want to make it so that the full email is not sent.

Can anyone suggest a good way that I could make it send:

- The first 2 characters of the address
- ...
- The last two before the @ to the end of the address

So for example

```
davesmith@live.com
```

is returned as

```
da...th@live.com
```

Comment: Well, this looks like fairly simple string manipulation to me. Use `IndexOf`, `Substring` etc.

Comment: Bit of a problem are emails with less then 4 character before @. Could start with
`var replace = Regex.Replace("davesmith@live.com", ".{2}(.*).{2}@.*", "...");`

Comment: @Matt - can you put that as an answer with an example. Thanks

Comment: Ok I did and modified, that shorter mails are possible.

Comment: Don't forget that according to the specification, the valid e-mail may include several @ and other strange characters. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: @kirmir Thanks for pointing this out. But since Regex is greey, this should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a problem are emails with less then 4 character before @. You Could start with

```
 private static string ShortenMail(string mail)
 {
     var regex = new Regex("^(.{1,2}).*?(.{0,2}@.*)$");
     return regex.Replace(mail, "$1...$2");
 }
```

And call it via `ShortenMail("davesmith@live.com");`

I changed it a bit, so shorter mails are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this maybe:

```
string email = "davesmith@live.com";
string maskedEmail = string.Format("{0}...{1}", email.Substring(0, 2), email.Substring(email.LastIndexOf("@") - 2));
```